# Prove that if the intersection of $n+1$ distinct spheres is non-empty then it has at most $n$ elements in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $D > 0$, and $C_1,\ldots,C_{n+1}$ some distinct points with $\|C - C_k\| = D$. Consider the balls $\mathcal{B}(C_k,r_k)$ for some $r_k > 0$. Can we prove that
$$\left| \bigcap_{k=1}^{n+1} \partial \mathcal{B}(C_k,r_k) \right| \leq n$$ i.e the intersection has at most $n$ elements?

---

### Later edit:

It might be true even for an intersection of $3$ such spheres ...

Comment: "it has a unique element"- what is "it"?

Comment: The intersection

Comment: and what is $\partial \mathcal{B}(\cdot, \cdot)$?

Comment: You could first try constructing such an intersection for $n=1,$ $n=2,$ $n=3$ and see how things work in low dimensions.

Comment: $\partial \mathcal{B}(C,R)$ is the frontier of the ball. Is the way I designate a sphere

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The statement from the title of the question is incorrect. For example, consider three circles in the plane ($n=2$):
$$
x^2+y^2=1, (x−1)^2+(y−1)^2=1, (x−2)^2+(y−2)^2=5
$$
Clearly, the points $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are common points of all three circles.
However, this statement is true if all the centers of the spheres do not lie in any hyperplane.

Comment: The title is not sufficient to describe the whole problem. The content of the problem is given in the body of the question. The centers of the spheres are themselves on a sphere ... huh?! So you say the statement is true if the centers of the spheres do not form a hyperplane?

Comment: @kabenyuk I have now relaxed the problem a little! Is the requirement that the centers of the spheres lie on a sphere, enough to guarantee that the number of the points in intersection is at most $n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/D15FB22917024962409980AC7D3C086D/S1446181117000372a.pdf/a-note-on-computing-the-intersection-of-spheres-in-mathbbrn-.pdf) shows that the intersection of $n$ spheres in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with affinely independent centers has at most $2$ elements. Now only remains to answer the question if $n$ distinct points on a sphere are always affinely independent? The answer is NO!